# c++ string manipulation to find same start/end ranges in a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string with ranges like eg. **"0-0,4-7,9-9"**, and I need to find out all ranges with same start and end and modify to them to "**0,4-7,9**".

I am not at ease with string manipulation and c++ so need some help.

**Input String:** "0-0,2-7,8-8,88-108"
**Output String:** "0,2-7,8,88-108"

Maximum digit value could be 4000 only.

In **PHP** I would need to do something like this in loop:

```
$pos = strpos($vlan_ranges, ",");
$number_range = strtok($number_ranges, ",");
$number = split("-", $range);
$number_start = $number[0];
$number_end   = $number[1];
```

But dont know how this could be done in c++. Not familiar with c++ syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Added: I have to this using standard String class alone. I can not use string manipulation engines.

Comment: Are you willing to use a regular expression engine?  If so, which one(s)?

Comment: No I can not use string manipulation engines :(

Comment: Why did you delete the other question? You could've simply waited for some one to answer.

Comment: I improved it here. And after your down vote many people would not have glanced at it. I am stuck and need to move on this.

Comment: @AJ. You're mistaken. I did not down-vote (and it's not too difficult to check for you). (When I do, I usually mention it along with a reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ( (orig_str.find(",") != std::string::npos) &&  (orig_str.find("-") != std::string::npos) )
{
sub = orig_str.substr(0, orig_str.find_first_of(","));
orig_str = orig_str.substr(orig_str.find_first_of(",")+1);
cout << "sub = " << sub << endl;
cout << "orig_str = " << orig_str << endl;
if (sub.substr(0,sub.find_first_of("-")) == sub.substr(sub.find_first_of("-")+1) )
{
    sub.erase(0, sub.find_first_of("-")+1);
    cout << "sub2 = " << sub << endl;
    final = final + sub + ",";
    cout << "final = " << final << endl;
}
else
{
    final = final + sub + ",";
}
}
cout << "final2 = " << final << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this could work:

```
std::string str = "1-1,2-3,4-4,...";
size_t number_digits;

for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{        
    if(str.find("-", i)) != std::string::npos))
    {
        number_digits = str.find_first_of(",", i) - i - 1;
        if (str.substr(i - number_digits, i - 1) == str.substr(i + 1, i + number_digits))
            str.erase(i-number_digits, number_digits + 1);
    }
}
```

Edit: actually I posted an infinite loop. Fixed now.

Comment: The loop condition might be `< str.size() - 1`, just in case an invalid string ending in `-` is passed in.

Comment: Maximum digit value could be 4000 only? I'm not sure if he means that 4000-4000 is valid. In which case you would have to search for the next "-" to construct, compare and erase the sub-strings.

Comment: @Ian Edwards: Yes you're right, this will only work for single digits. Edited again.

Comment: Yes 4000-4000 is valid. I will try this.

Comment: @Marian Its crashing : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr Aborted

Comment: i =0 and number_digits =2 when this happens.

Comment: And even 88-108 is a valid range.

Comment: I've made a change, let me know if that helps. I can't actually test it at the moment. I also think you can replace the statement if the first if with: (str[i] == "-").