# Getting out_of_range error in this string manipulation code

Tags: c++, string

Hi I am hitting **std::out_of_range: basic_string::substr**
in the following code. Have been trying hard to fix it but cant get it done.

```
std::string orig_str = "1-1,2-3,4-4,56-75,77-77";
size_t number_digits;
for (size_t i = 0; i < orig_str.size(); ++i)
{
    number_digits = orig_str.find_first_of(",", i) - i - 1;
    if(orig_str.find("-", i) != std::string::npos)
    if (orig_str.substr(i - number_digits, i - 1) == orig_str.substr(i + 1, i + number_digits))
    orig_str.erase(i-number_digits, number_digits + 1);            
}
```

Basically this code is manipulating string to remove some ranges
Expected behavior is:
**Input String:** "0-0,2-7,88-88" **Output String:** "0,2-7,88"

Comment: Add `try`/`catch` around the string calls to find out which call is triggering the exception, and print out the `orig_str` and `i` and see if that gives you a hint.

Comment: @user315052 i =0 and number_digits =2 when this happens.

Comment: @user315052 Its still "1-1,2-3,4-4,56-75,77-77". So this is happening on the first call of substr().

Comment: if `i = 0`, then you are passing in invalid numbers to `substr` aren't you?

Comment: orig_str.substr(0 - 2, 0 -1) is the first call while orig_str.substr(1,2) is the second.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12774/discussion-between-user315052-and-aj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJ, this is the pseudo code we discussed in our chat:

```
input_string = "1-1,2-3,4-4,56-75,77-77"
output_string = ""
while (input_string is not empty)
    sub = input_string.substr(up to first comma)
    input_string = input_string.substr(after first comma)
    if (sub.substr(up to dash) == sub.substr(after dash))
        output_string += sub.substr(up to dash)
    else
        output_string += sub
    if (input_string is not empty)
        output_string += ","
```

Comment: I finished the code and its here as an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099476/c-string-manipulation-to-find-same-start-end-ranges-in-a-string#comment14536527_11099476

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the length of the original string, and also modifies it and hereby changing the length. The compiler might optimize the call to `orig_str.size()` meaning it will fetch the length once and letting you iterate more than new length of the string.

You should probably change to keep the `orig_str` as is was from the beginning (otherwise it is named very badly) and put the results in a new string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int flag = 0;
    int num_ch;
    char * fnum = NULL, * snum = NULL;
    int numOfLoop = orig_str.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfLoop; i++)
    {
        if(orig_str[i] == '-')
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if(orig_str[i] == ',')
        {
            int ret = strcmp(fnum, snum);
            if(ret == 0)
            {
                int sizeOfNUM = strlen(fnum);
                int numOfChToReplace = sizeOfNUM + sizeOfNUM + 1;
                orig_str.replace(i - numOfChToReplace,numOfChToReplace, fnum); 
                numOfLoop = numOfLoop - (sizeOfNUM + 1);
                i = i - (sizeOfNUM + 1);
            }

            flag = 0;
            delete [] fnum;
            delete [] snum;
            fnum = NULL;
            snum = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if(flag == 1)
            {
                if(snum == NULL)
                {
                    snum = new char[2];
                    snum[0] = orig_str[i];
                    snum[1] = '\0';
                }
                else
                {
                    int size = strlen(snum);
                    char * tmp = snum;
                    snum = new char[size + 2];
                    for( int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                        snum[j] = tmp[j];
                    snum[size] = orig_str[i];
                    snum[size + 1] = '\0';
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if(fnum == NULL)
                {
                    fnum = new char[2];
                    fnum[0] = orig_str[i];
                    fnum[1] = '\0';
                }
                else
                {
                    int size = strlen(fnum);
                    char * tmp = fnum;
                    fnum = new char[size + 2];
                    for( int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                        fnum[j] = tmp[j];
                    fnum[size] = orig_str[i];
                    fnum[size + 1] = '\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int ret = strcmp(fnum, snum);
    if(ret == 0)
    {
        int sizeOfNUM = strlen(fnum);
        int numOfChToReplace = sizeOfNUM + sizeOfNUM + 1;
        orig_str.replace(i - numOfChToReplace,numOfChToReplace, fnum); 
        numOfLoop = numOfLoop - (sizeOfNUM + 1);
        i = i - (sizeOfNUM + 1);
    }

    flag = 0;
    delete [] fnum;
    delete [] snum;
    fnum = NULL;
    snum = NULL;

    std::cout << orig_str.c_str() << std::endl;
```